# A property of the Legendre symbol

Tags: analytic-number-theory

There is a property of Legendre symbol:

$$
\sum_{0\leq k \leq p-1} \left(\frac{k^2-d}{p}\right)=\sum_{0\leq j \leq p-1}\left(1+\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)\right)\left(\frac{j-d}{p}\right)
$$

with $\gcd(d,p)=1$. I already know that 
$$
\sum_{0\leq k \leq p-1} \left(1+\left(\frac{k^2-d}{p}\right)\right)
$$

is the number of solutions for $x^2 \equiv k^2-d \pmod{p}$.  I am wondering how to go from here to prove this property of Legendre symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $g$ is a function on $\mathbb Z_p$, then:

$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z_p} g(k^2)=\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z_p}(1+\left(\frac{j}{p}\right))g(j)$$

That's because $1+\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)$ is the number of square roots of $j$, modulo $p$.

So you can change the RHS to be:

$$\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z_p} g(j) \hspace{0.2em}\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_p}_{n^2= j}1$$

Switching sums, you get:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z_p}\hspace{0.2em}\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z_p}_{j= n^2}g(j)$$

But the inner sum is just one term, so you get:

$$\sum_{0\leq n \leq p-1}g(n^2)$$

In your case, $g(n) = \left(\frac{n-d}{p}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative proof that is much the same as Thomas Andrews':

Recall that the Legendre symbol is a multiplicative quadratic [character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_%28mathematics%29#Multiplicative_character) on [$\mathbb{F}_p$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Finite_fields).  In particular, by [orthogonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Orthogonality_relations), we have

$$
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left( \frac{x}{p} \right) = 0.
$$

This statement follows easily from the fact that there are just as many residues as nonresidues in $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p$ is odd, but I think it is important to understand the more general structure.  We wish to find a value for

$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{F}_p}\left(\frac{k^2 - d}{p} \right).
$$

We have

$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left(\frac{k^2 - d}{p} \right) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left(\frac{y}{p}\right)N(y),
$$

where we made the Change of Variables $y = k^2 - d$, and

$$
N(y) = \# \{y \in \mathbb{F}_p : y = k^2 - d\}.
$$

Note that $y = k^2 - d$ has a solution if and only if $y + d$ is a square.  Hence,

$$
N(y) = 1 + \left( \frac{y+d}{p} \right).
$$

Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left( \frac{k^2 - d}{p} \right) &= \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left( 1 + \left( \frac{y+d}{p} \right) \right) \left(\frac{y}{p} \right).
\end{align}$$

Finally, the change of variables $j \to y - d$ yields what we want:

$$
\sum_{j \in \mathbb{F}_p} \left(1 + \left( \frac{j}{p} \right) \right) \left( \frac{j - d}{p} \right).
$$

The advantage to this method is that it required basically no ingenuity.  Applying the change of variables made it clear the quantity we wanted to evaluate (which was $N(y)$ using my notation), and this was straight-forward using your own observations.